# C++ Randomly change var to enum that is not itself

Tags: c++, random, enums

At the moment, I can randomly choose from an enum and assign it to my variable:

```
(*itL).setDirection(static_cast<LadyDirection>(rand()% NUM_DIRECTIONS));

void Ladybug::setDirection(LadyDirection temp_direction)
{
    this->direction = temp_direction;
}

enum LadyDirection
{
    North,
    East,
    South,
    West,
    NUM_DIRECTIONS
};
```

What I want to do is make this change to a random enum value, that isn't what it currently is. Eg. If the direction is == North, set it to East, West or South, randomly.

I know I could do this with a few if/elseif statements, but I'd rather know if there's someway to do this nicer.

Thanks.

Comment: just  change direction to any random direction (different then actual) So just pick any random direction as you have and if different then original stop if not loop ...

Comment: I may not have made myself clear then, sorry for the confusion. I want to change this->direction to a value in enum that isn't what it already is. I think what you wrote above should work, I'll give it a try.

Comment: When I read it 3th time it was clearer :) (ignore the deleted comment part)

Comment: Thanks, one of the answers gave a good solution, which was also your solution. :) Any idea why this got a -1? I don't really see a problem with my question........

Comment: hard to say but most likely someone got the same impression of your text as I at the first read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of the list of directions as a circular list, generate a random number between (and including) `1` and `NUM_DIRECTIONS - 1` and use it as a number of steps to move into the list:

```
void LadyBug::setDirection(int nSteps)
{
    this->direction = static_cast<LadyDirection>(
                     (this->direction + nSteps) % NUM_DIRECTIONS
    );
}

(*itL).setDirection(1 + rand()%(NUM_DIRECTIONS - 1)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this instead of your first line of code

```
r = rand() % (NUM_DIRECTIONS - 1); // limit the random to 0..2
new_direction = (old_direction + r + 1) % NUM_DIRECTIONS;
```

Answer (score 1):

> could do this with a few if/elseif statements

I think you overestimate the complexity: just use `rand() % (NUM_DIRECTIONS - 2)` (so you'll never get `West` directly) and if you happen to hit on the current direction, use `West` instead, something like:

```
LadyDirection dir = itL->getDirection();
itL->setDirection(static_cast<LadyDirection>(rand() % (NUM_DIRECTIONS - 2));
if (itL->getDirection() == dir)
    itL->setDirection(West);
```

It would be simpler as a member function.